# PowerShell and Single Threaded Apartment

Tags: multithreading, powershell, batch-file, wpk

I have developed a small GUI tool in PowerShell using [WPK](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerShellPack).

I have the following start up command

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file PowerTools.ps1 -noexit -sta
```

I am getting the following error.

```
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "0" argument(s): "The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this."
At \WindowsPowerShell\Modules\WPK\GeneratedControls\PresentationFramework.ps1:34
10 char:29
+         $Object = New-Object <<<<  System.Windows.Window
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :     ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

From my Googling, STA stands up "single-threaded apartment", I noticed that that powershell.exe has the "-sta" flag, but that does not help either.

The essence of my ps1 file looks like the following

```
Import-Module WPK

function get-gui()
{
      New-Window  -WindowStartupLocation CenterScreen `
       -Width 1200 -Height 200 -Show {

      New-Grid -Rows 32, 32, 32, 32 -Columns 110, 200* {
            ...
          }
        }
    }
}

get-gui
```

Any hints please?

(I did spend quite a bit of time doing my own research)

Comment: why do you use this batch ? Simply call PS like this :
`powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file PowerTools.ps1 -noexit`

Comment: Thanks! I simplified my post above. But I still get the same error as before :( Any hint?

Comment: please verify AppartmentState of `[System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace]::DefaultRunspace`

Comment: "STA" within ISE, "Unknown" with powershell.exe and a ps1 file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It it this simple! :) Thanks for your guidance, Kayasax!

```
powerShell -sta -file PowerTools.ps1
```

Comment: Note the difference: I had `powerShell -file PowerTools.ps1 -sta` which didn't work. Can someone explain the difference please? Somehow, my old version has the STA associated with the ps1 file and my new version has STA associated with powershell?

Comment: you can check this post, where the script detect if powershell is in sta mode and relaunch it if it is not the case http://powershell-scripting.com/index.php?option=com_joomlaboard&Itemid=76&func=view&id=7157&catid=5#7157

Answer (score 2):

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847736.aspx says that `-file` must be last in the in the list of options because everything after the file name is interpreted as parameters to the file.  That is why it works when `-sta` is listed before `-file`, but does not work after `-file`.